# Is it possible to test for non-normality (in a general way)?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm just curious and trying to get my head around this question.  I feel like this requires applying a probability space structure to the space of all distributions that are not normal, but, I'm thinking maybe someone will have an awesome answer to help me wrap my head around this question.

And I guess I'm deliberately leaving what I mean by "distributions" unspecific here in case someone has some idea like, "if you assume your data is coming from a distribution with a continuous pdf...."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test The back-of-the-envelope one is particularly easy to use, if limited in its applicability (e.g. it doesn't care very much about asymmetry in the data).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test

Comment: It is unlikely that in any real-world situation that you could end up with (exactly) a normal distribution.  So the general result is "No, it's not normal."  What you need to address is what characteristics of normality are needed and how far away from those characteristics can you be before it matters to the problem at hand.